# hit and miss transform in image processing

Tags: image-processing, mathematical-morphology

This [page](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm) talks about `hit and miss`, and it says:

> It is easier to describe it by considering s1 and s2 as a single structuring element with 1s for pixels of s1 and 0s for pixels of s2; in this case the hit-and-miss transform assigns 1 to an output pixel only if the object (with the value of 1) and background (with the value of 0) pixels in the structuring element exactly match object (1) and background (0) pixels in the input image. Oterwise that pixel is set to the background value (0).

Why should **2** structuring elements applied in `hit and miss` transform?

For example, here are 2 elements:

```
[ 1 * 1 ]      [ * 0 * ]
[ * 1 * ]      [ 0 * 0 ] 
[ 1 * 1 ]      [ * 0 * ]
```

BUT, why can't I just use **1** element like this:

```
[ 1 0 1 ]
[ 0 1 0 ]
[ 1 0 1 ]
```

?

Comment: You can - it's just the logic that changes because the SE is logically two SE's. [There's a better description here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hitmiss.htm) if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The Hit-or-Miss transform as the name suggest uses 2 structuring elements to identify structures which are specific to the fore ground(C) and background(D).

[image]

This gives some freedom in having different orientations in between the Foreground and background Structuring elements. [Applications](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/notes/hit-or-miss.pdf) are generally Corner point, end point, simple point detection(here the foreground are points/pixels and their degree of connectivity with other foreground pixels, while the background fills the various orientations), Thinnings, Skeletonization, Pruning, and various composite pattern detections. The Hit or miss transform was one of the basic operators to be [documented](http://cmm.ensmp.fr/~serra/pdf/birth_of_mm.pdf) along with Erosion and Dilation operators.

The matlab implementation now uses the [LUT](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/makelut.html) to efficiently code and extract patterns, perform skeletonization and various other 2x2 and 3x3 lookup based [non linear filtering operations](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/bwlookup.html).